# Using String_split and pivot function on comma separated value column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to **string_split**  a **comma separated value** column then **pivot** the value of the result into a **week, day , hour**. Finally I need to group the numeric values by **sub_issue_key** and **assignee**.
here is a sample of the data, the table name **dbo.brut_data**.

| sub_task_key (unique values) | Assignee (only English letters) | Σ Remaining Estimate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dev-1 | xzr ag | 1 week, 3 days, 7 hours |
| dev-2 | xzr ag | 2 days, 6 hours |
| unit_test-1 | ezs ak | 6 hours |

Here is what I did, this code splits the [Σ Remaining Estimate] column and returns it into multiple rows

```
SELECT sub_task_key, [Assignee],  value
FROM dbo.brut_data
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([Σ Remaining Estimate], ',') AS s
```

But I don't know how to pivot to match this result, could someone give me a helping hand thanks

Wanted results:

| sub_task_key | Assignee | weeks | days | hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dev-1 | xzr ag | 1 | 3 | 7 |
| dev-2 | xzr ag |  | 2 | 6 |
| unit_test-1 | ezs ak |  |  | 6 |

Comment: Please show us your desired results and your attempt.

Comment: If truly stuck ... at a minimum show us your desired results.

Comment: There is no such thing as SQL Server 2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following using the `STRING_SPLIT` function and conditional aggregation to pivot the data:

```
SELECT T.sub_task_key, T.Assignee,
  ISNULL
  (
    MAX(Case When S.value Like '%week%' Then TRIM('weeks ' FROM S.value) End) 
    , 0
  ) AS weeks,
  ISNULL
  (
    MAX(Case When S.value Like '%day%' Then TRIM('days ' FROM S.value) End) 
    , 0
  ) AS days,
  ISNULL
  (
    MAX(Case When S.value Like '%hour%' Then TRIM('hours ' FROM S.value) End) 
    , 0
  ) AS hours
FROM brut_data T CROSS APPLY 
     STRING_SPLIT(T.Remaining_Estimate, ',') S
GROUP BY T.sub_task_key, T.Assignee
ORDER BY T.sub_task_key, T.Assignee
```

Or you could use the pivot operator as the following:

```
SELECT sub_task_key, Assignee,
 ISNULL(TRIM('weeks ' FROM w), 0) AS weeks,
 ISNULL(TRIM('days ' FROM d), 0) AS days,
 ISNULL(TRIM('hours ' FROM h), 0) AS hours  
FROM
( 
  SELECT T.sub_task_key, T.Assignee,
         S.value,
         CASE 
          WHEN S.value LIKE '%week%' THEN 'w'
          WHEN S.value LIKE '%day%' THEN 'd'
          WHEN S.value LIKE '%hour%' THEN 'h'
         END AS intervals 
  FROM brut_data T CROSS APPLY 
       STRING_SPLIT(T.Remaining_Estimate, ',') S
) D
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(value) FOR intervals IN ([w], [d], [h])
) P
ORDER BY sub_task_key, Assignee
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XyK-o9ck)